# How to resolve a possible multiplicative overflow to get correct modulus operation?

Tags: rust, modulo, integer-overflow, int128

I have to perform `(a * b) % m`, but `a`, `b`, *and* `m` are 128-bit unsigned types, and overflow during multiplication is a large possibility. How can I still get a correct answer (probably using `%` more)?

I'm trying to implement the modular exponent function in Rust, where the largest built-in type is `u128` (which is the max I can use). All three variables are really large, and so `(a * b) > 2^128` is easy. I can use `a.overflowing_mul(b)` to detect whether an overflow occurred, but I do not know how to go back from the overflowed result (which can be thought of as `(a * b) % 2^128`) to get `(a * b) % m`.

My modular exponent code looks like this (currently no overflowing support is added):

```
fn mod_exp(b: u128, e: u128, m: u128) {
    (0..e).fold(1, |x, _| (x * b) % m)
    //                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

From a mathematical perspective:

```
(a * b) % m IS ACTUALLY (a * b) % B % m
| B = current base (2^128)
```

Examples:

```
// Mathematical
(9 * 13) % 11 = 7
// Real (base 20):
(9 * 13) % (B = 20) % 11 = 6
         ^^^^^^^^^^        ^ should be 7

(8 * 4) % 14 = 4
(8 * 4) % (B = 16) % 14 = 0
        ^^^^^^^^^^        ^ should be 4
```

Comment: I don't want to say that "it can't be done" right away, but wouldn't it be much safer and easier to just use big integers from the `num` crate? Do you have any good reasons to go through this exercise? And by the way: (0 .. e).fold( ... * ... ) is nothing you would want to do with an `e: u128`, because it would take the clock of your CPU roughly 228951566670 lifetimes of the universe to tick 2^128 times. See: [Square and multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) (that's the easy part, doesn't help you with multiplication overflow).

Comment: I've given up on using `u128`s and I'm just using the `num` crate now. Thanks to @AndreyTyukin for the tip on square-and-multiply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This implementation, based on splitting the 128-bit product into four 64-bit products, is five times as fast as [`num_bigint::BigUint`](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.2.2/num_bigint/struct.BigUint.html), ten times as fast as [`uint::U256`](https://docs.rs/uint/0.5.0/uint/struct.U256.html), and 2.3 times as fast as [`gmp::mpz::Mpz`](https://docs.rs/rust-gmp/0.5.0/gmp/mpz/struct.Mpz.html):

```
fn mul_mod(a: u128, b: u128, m: u128) -> u128 {
    if m <= 1 << 64 {
        ((a % m) * (b % m)) % m
    } else {
        let add = |x: u128, y: u128| x.checked_sub(m - y).unwrap_or_else(|| x + y);
        let split = |x: u128| (x >> 64, x & !(!0 << 64));
        let (a_hi, a_lo) = split(a);
        let (b_hi, b_lo) = split(b);
        let mut c = a_hi * b_hi % m;
        let (d_hi, d_lo) = split(a_lo * b_hi);
        c = add(c, d_hi);
        let (e_hi, e_lo) = split(a_hi * b_lo);
        c = add(c, e_hi);
        for _ in 0..64 {
            c = add(c, c);
        }
        c = add(c, d_lo);
        c = add(c, e_lo);
        let (f_hi, f_lo) = split(a_lo * b_lo);
        c = add(c, f_hi);
        for _ in 0..64 {
            c = add(c, c);
        }
        add(c, f_lo)
    }
}
```

(**Warning:** none of these implementations are suitable for use in cryptographic code, since they are not hardened against side channel attacks.)

Comment: Instead of looping with `c = add(c, c)`, can't you use `checked_shl` and use the same `unwrap_or_else`? Would that increase speed?

Comment: @ARaspiK I’m not sure exactly what you’re suggesting, but it sounds unlikely. The current implementation carefully maintains the invariant `c < m` without doing any modulo operations in the inner loops (128-bit modulo is itself [implemented](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/release_80/lib/builtins/udivmodti4.c) with a loop over 128 bits). `checked_shl` wouldn’t do that.

Comment: @ARaspiK I just found a separate ~15% improvement, though.